# Write specific line in loop to CSV using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I'm working on a function to parse through a CSV file and insert each row into a db.

However, if there are any db specific errors (integrity constraints, etc) i want to write the line to an error CSV.

```
def insert_query(file):
    conn = db_connection()[0]
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    try:
        with open(file, 'r') as f:
            logging.critical('Attempting to insert data into table:')
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            columns = next(reader)
            query = '[insert query]'
            success = 0
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            num_row = df.shape[0]
            for data in reader:
                if num_row > 1:
                    try:
                        cursor.execute(query, data)
                        conn.commit()
                        logging.warning('Record inserted successfully')
                        success += 1
                        logging.critical(str(success) + ' rows inserted successfully')
                    except DatabaseError as e:
                        err, = e.args
                        # logging.critical(str(success) + ' rows inserted.')
                        logging.critical('Error: ' + str(data) + ' Error-Message:' + str(err.message))
                        error_file = pd.DataFrame(data)
                        error_file.to_csv('error.csv')
                        pass
            logging.critical(str(success) + ' out of ' + str(num_row) + ' rows were inserted successfully')
            cursor.close()
            conn.close()
    except Exception as e:
        logging.critical('Encountered exception ' + str(e))
```

Currently, this query functions great except for

```
                        error_file = pd.DataFrame(data)
                        error_file.to_csv('error.csv')
```

It is writing each value per line.

I want to make it append to CSV as such:

```
FName, LName, Address, Phone 
john, smith, 10 help st, 4441342
```

Instead I'm seeing:

```
0,john
1,smith
2,10 help st,
3,4441342
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend declaring the DataFrame `error_file` outside the try statement and at the start and then append each error line to this DataFrame. At the end of the code, export the DataFrame to a .csv file.

Comment: since i'm already using csv package to loop through each line, would it be simpler for me to just store the errors as a list and then print them to a file after?

Comment: List or dataframe doesn't matter as long as memory is not a concern. If memory is a concern, use list.